# log4d vs log4delphi

Tags: delphi, logging, delphi-2009

does anyone know what is the difference between log4d vs log4delphi? could you recommend one of them that you used and satisfied with ? or claim they are the same? or do you use other "logger" that you could recommend ?

in the site of [log4delphi](http://log4delphi.sourceforge.net/faq.html#Why+create+new+logging+project+for+Delphi?%2bAnalogous%2bproject%2bLog4D%2balready%2bexists?) it states:

> Log4D last updated their CVS 16 Months ago, the project has had no
>   recent activity since then. They also have no file releases which
>   means new users would have to get source code from the CVS repository
>   which is not good.
>
> Log4D is also a direct port of Log4J while Log4Delphi is loosely based
>   on Log4J which means that Log4Delphi does not have to follow what
>   Log4J is doing, we can deviate from log4j at any time, which is a good
>   thing, considering the numerous differences between Java and Delphi.

update:
after working with te delphi4d , it is possible to export to html this way:

```
uses log4d;
var
  appender:TLogFileAppender;
  logger:TLoglogger;
begin
  appender := TLogRollingFileAppender.Create('name','log.html');
  appender.Layout := TLogHTMLLayout.Create;
  TLogBasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);    
  TLogLogger.GetRootLogger.Level := All;
  Logger := TLogLogger.GetLogger('loggerName');
    Logger.Fatal('fatal output');
    Logger.Error('error output');
    Logger.Warn('warn output');
    Logger.Info('info output');
    Logger.Debug('starting debug');
end;
```

update2:log4delphi is released for delphi 6 or delphi 7. meaning extra work needs to upgrade to later delphi.

update 3:
log4d is the same as log4j, and very fast to pickup and use.

Comment: Isn't this project also dead? The last update of this page was in 2006...

Comment: Dead? is there anything else to do with log4d? how complex should it be? some code are written once, and left alone.

Comment: Questions like "which is better" are forbidden in StackOverflow, you may want to edit your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: [DCC Error] Log4D.pas(446): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TClassList'
log4d does not compile.

Comment: it needs Condition Define: DELPHI5_UP added

Comment: or just take ready-made `jedi.inc` and stop using ancient no more supported Coindition Defines :-)

Comment: Please don't close this question, as someone else might be looking for log4j logger for delphi, and would like to know what is the status of the projects.

Comment: This topic was useful for me. Too bad it was closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add another "logger", as you requested, I recommend our [Open Source logging classes](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons).

It has a "KISS" design, very diverse from Log4J and all Log4* adaptations. Idea was to develop something fast, stable, powerful and dedicated to Delphi for business applications. For instance, it does not create XML files, but plain text files.

It has logging features (with a set of levels, not a hierarchy of level), can serialize content, exception interception with stack trace (and unit / method name with line numbers!), method execution timing, log compression and auto-archival.

A [log viewer](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/20/Enhanced-Log-viewer) is available and very fast, and allows method profiling from any log file.

We use it on production for huge programs, from Delphi 5 up to XE3, with a lot of benefit. Just having the exceptions logged, and execution timing changes everything.

It is part of our *mORMot* framework, but can used without it. Just some units to link, and that's all.

It is free, and maintained, whereas your Log4D* projects sounds not yet active.

Comment: err, link to the logger?

Comment: @none What about the first link in my answer?

Comment: i did want to test your logger, however there is no link to download the actual logger, even inside the first link. i gave up, and chose a different logger. your logger looks promising.

Comment: It is part of the *mORMot* framework. Just use `SynCommons.pas` unit, and you will get the `TSynLog` class. Download and take a look at the corresponding section of the [mORMot SAD 1.18 pdf](http://synopse.info/files/pdf/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the FAQ you're referencing, they are not the same.

You can easily confirm this by downloading both and comparing the files.

While Log4D last download (log4d-src 0.9 2007-06-12) 38.2 Kb contains just 4 pas files, Log4Delphi last download (log4delphi 0.8 Melloware 2010-11-16) 1.7 Mb contains 27 pas files just in the src/delphi folder, plus other folders with unit tests and packages.

Also comparing the dtd both projects contains shows the xml format is different and incompatible.

Both projects looks outdated. Log4Delphi includes packages for D6 and D7.

If one is based in the other, I don't know. Log4Delphi looks more complex, even the 0.1 version have a very different file set.

Comment: the log4d has tests and more complex pas if you dive to the repository. they want to give simple start for new users, which is smart.

Comment: The question is about the different features of the two logging frameworks.

Comment: @ssh, in fact there are different questions. I'm answering to if they are the same.